# magento write to or read from session using <session_save> db value

Tags: php, magento, session

I'm working for a company that has chosen to use the db for session handling in magento.  Specifically, in /app/etc/local.xml there is this entry:

```
    <session_save><![CDATA[db]]></session_save>
```

I understand that the data is being saved in the table `core_session`.  However, I'm not familiar with how to read from and write to the session object.

with `session_start()` it's easy, I just write

```
$_SESSION['status']='OK'; //write
$status= $_SESSION['status']; //read
```

What is the equivalent method when magento is using `db` as a session storage method?  I assume it's a class method.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each module in Magento can have its own session object for saving namespaced values to/from the session.  For example, to set the variable `foo_bar` in the "core" session namespace, all you need to do is call

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setFooBar('Some Value');
```

To do the same thing in the "customer" session namespace,

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setFooBar('Some Value');
```

You'd then fetch these values with

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFooBar();
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getFooBar();
```

The basic idea is Magento provides you with these session objects so you don't need to worry about starting/stopping the session, or managing collisions in `$_SESSION`.  Behind the scenes Magento's still using `$_SESSION` and `session_start` -- but its handling those details for you so you can use a session model/singleton just like you'd use any model in Magento.

You also might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9803979/whats-the-difference-between-the-different-magento-session-types) useful.